# div Background Image Cutted

Tags: html, css

I defined  with background image as following.Html:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <h4>Entities Presenter</h4>
    <div class="bg">
        <canvas id="my-canvas" class="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bg {
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("wp2753284.jpg");

    /* Full height */
    height: 100%;

    /* Center and scale the image nicely */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But the background image after definitions above displayed cutted ( from top and bottom), Is there something wrong in the definition ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

instead of background-size: cover;
try  background-size: contain;